# Why doesn't Google Structured Data Testing Tool load external JSON-LD files referenced in @context?

Tags: json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

While playing with [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), I noticed that it can handle inline `@context` in JSON-LD alright:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "Product": "https://example.com/Product",
        "name": "https://example.com/name"
    },
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "test"
}
```

[image]

But fails to handle external JSON-LD files referenced in `@context`:

```
{
    "@context": "https://example.com/context.jsonld",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "test"
}
```

[image]

Instead, **it resolves the terms relative to the current URL**.

And when I check example.com's server logs, I can see that no attempt was made to request the context file.

**Is this a willful violation of JSON-LD because Google only cares about specific vocabularies** such as Schema.org, or did I miss something?

Bonus question: can we expect the same behaviour from GoogleBot, i.e. not downloading external JSON-LD context files?

Comment: Note: Yandex's [Structured data validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/) does not load external context files either.